# A-Star algorithm details

Tags: computer-science, graph-algorithm, a-star

I started A* algorithm but i don't realize how it works in details .

for example , I have a graph and it's :

A -> B = 9 (not 90 as originally asked by mistake)

A -> C = 20

C -> D = 40

now i want to start from A and go to D using mentioned paths.

If i use this heuristic function : h(n) = distance of direct way to D 
direct distance between B and D is 2 but there is not any path between B and D .

What i want to know is that :

Does A* algorithm first go to B and then return to A again ( Because there is not any path between B and D ( goal )?

or My heuristic function is not admissible ? ( but i'v seen in text books , it is ok )

Comment: Not sure your question belongs here, but in this case: A* begins at A with a score of 0. It finds B and assigns a score of 90, then finds C and assigns a score of 20. It then closes A. So A is closed, B and C are "open". C has the lowest score of the open nodes, so it goes there. Now it finds D and stops, because that was the end point.

Comment: In a more interesting example, B would have a lower score than C, so it would go to B. It would find nothing to link to (so add no new open nodes), and close B. Now only C is open, so it goes there. The rest is as before.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should give us more details on your function.

Generally speaking, A* should return the path if it exists, so you may treat a non-existing path as a infinite-cost or just as a "stop-here" sign.
When you reach the end of the path without reaching the destination, you roll back to the previous node with other possibilities. So the answer to your first question is 'yes'.